# Improving mdadm RAID-6 write speed

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a mdadm RAID-6 in my home server of 5x1Tb WD Green HDDs.
Read speed is more than enough - 268 Mb/s in dd.
But write speed is just 37.1 Mb/s.
(Both tested via dd on 48Gb file, RAM size is 1Gb, block size used in testing is 8kb)

Could you please suggest why write speed is so low and is there any ways to improve it?
CPU usage during writing is just 25% (i.e. half of 1 core of Opteron 165)
No business critical data there & server is UPS-backed.

mdstat is:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid6 sda1[0] sdd1[4] sde1[3] sdf1[2] sdb1[1]
      2929683456 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 1024k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Any suggestions?

Things like writeback, barrier, nobh didn't helped. DD blocksize=1M, 8M didn't changed anything. It looks like mdadm physically reads sectors to calculate parity even if it does not matter... Is that correct?

**Update:** Speed degradation after altered stripe cache was actually because 1 HDD probably failed during testing, nice :-D

**Resolved:** After increasing stripe cache & switching to external bitmap, my speeds are 160 Mb/s writes, 260 Mb/s reads. :-D

Comment: Hey Bars.. What have you tweaked and after what change did the performance drop down to 120Mb/s?

I am having a similar issue but my performance is way worse :(

Any suggestions would be useful! Thanks!

Comment: In my case I had a diskfail in the middle of optimization :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried tuning /sys/block/mdX/md/stripe_cache_size?

According to [this forum post](http://avforum.no/forum/ny-av-automatisering-distribusjon-hjemmet-ny/74083-oppsett-av-linux-server-29.html#post1579643) (in Norwegian, sorry) "tuning this parameter is more essential the more disks and the faster system you have":

> On my system I get the best performance using the value 8192. If I use the default value of 256 the write performance drops 66%.

Quoting his speed for comparison:

> Disks: 8xSeagate 2TB LP (5900RPM) in mdadm
> RAID6 (-n 512) (stripe_size_cache=8192).
>
> CPU: Intel X3430 (4x2.4GHz, 8GB DDR3 ECC RAM)
>
> Speed: 387 MB/s sequential write, 704 MB/s sequential read, 669 random seeks per sec.

My home server has almost the same disks as you, using RAID 5:

> Disks: 4x1.5TB WD Green in RAID 5 (stripe_size_cache=256 - the default)
>
> CPU: Intel i7 920 (2.66 GHz, 6 GB RAM)
>
> Speed: 60 MB/s sequential write, 138 MB/s sequential read (according to Bonnie++)

So it looks like sequential write performance is around 50% of read performance.

For what performance to expect, the [Linux Raid Wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Overview#RAID-5) says about RAID 5:

> Reads are almost similar to RAID-0
> reads, writes can be either rather
> expensive (requiring read-in prior to
> write, in order to be able to
> calculate the correct parity
> information, such as in database
> operations), or similar to RAID-1
> writes (when larger sequential writes
> are performed, and parity can be
> calculated directly from the other
> blocks to be written).

And about RAID 6:

> Read performance is similar to RAID-5 but write performance is worse.

Comment: Write speed dropped to 15-20 Mb/s, read speed down to 110 :-S This just does not make sence :-(

Comment: Try some other values, see what happens. Not an expert on this, but I have WD Greens (4x1.5TB) in md RAID 5 with the same issue - rather slow write speed. My system is down at the moment, but I'll experiment at my end as well, and update here if I manage to improve it.

Comment: BTW: Do you have AHCI enabled? Which file system - ext3, ext4?

Comment: Not sure about AHCI, it's very hard to take a look at BIOS. ext4.

Comment: Damn, stuck with 120Mb/s reading speed, can't get back to my 268 :-( This is so frustrating... I don't see why can't mdadm read or write data linearly at ~3x90 Mb/s... It's just silly.

Comment: I hope you have a data backup? When experimenting like this you may well end up having to rebuild the raid from scratch. Especially when tweaking stripe sizes and similar, it takes a complete rebuild to see the effect.

Comment: Well, I doubt home user might have 3Tb backup :-D

Comment: And I doubt any stripe settings should degrade write performance that much :-|

Comment: Your original numbers aren't that far off what I would expect. With (almost) the same disks as you, I get 60MB/s write and 138 MB/s read in RAID 5. 3x90 MB/s writes is unrealistic (to the best of my knowledge), there's quite a bit overhead to software RAID writing.

Comment: And for backups - I actually do have 4TB backups as a home user :) Spread over multiple external disks, a small NAS and the remaining computers in the house, but I have it. Not that the data are critical, but it took months to rip all my DVDs, and I'd rather not have to do it all over again :)

Comment: After fixing array I've got 134Mb/s writes and 270Mb/s reads. Writes are limited by CPU, so I guess after upgrade it will go higher. Best stripe cache for me is 4096, 8192 shows same speed (maybe faster CPU will show that 8192 is faster)

Comment: @BarsMonster Well your doubt is wrong. I do. Of course that was years ago but even so it was a serious undervaluing on your part. I remember back when 1GB was released and everyone more or less said 'You could never fill this in a lifetime!' How wrong we were...

Answer (score 4):

try

`echo 32768 > /sys/block/md0/md/stripe_cache_size`

and check ;)

Comment: In previous answer we were testing different stripe_cache_sizes. Setting it to 32768 didn't improved anything. I am still at ~100Mb/sec writes even after upgrade (E8500 CPU, 8Gb ram and 8x1Tb array)

Comment: ABSURD! That *instantly* increased my write performance from ~70MB/s to ~360MB/s!?! Oh my god. W-T-F is this not default?!?

Comment: Oh my word. This really works...     From  [================>....]  recovery = 82.1% (1604609136/1953382144) finish=122.7min speed=47348K/sec   to       [================>....]  recovery = 82.3% (1607712880/1953382144) finish=56.2min speed=102451K/sec

Comment: In my testing, the value of 8192 seems sufficient. Despite throwing everything I had to test with at an array, I couldn't get stripe_cache_active to spike higher than the low 7000s.