# Improving performance on mdadm RAID5 reshape

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid5

I am currently a few days in to what appears to be 13 day *reshape* of a RAID5 array which consists of 6x12TB SATA NAS drives running on a 12-core server with 64GB of RAM.

I've been reading some posts here and elsewhere on resync performance, notably:

- [Improving mdadm RAID-6 write speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19325/improving-mdadm-raid-6-write-speed)
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-raid-increase-resync-rebuild-speed.html

These have suggested making some changes to various system settings which results in:

- /sys/block/md127/md/stripe_cache_size = 32768
- /sys/block/md127/md/sync_max = max
- dev.raid.speed_limit_min = 100000
- dev.raid.speed_limit_max = 5000000
- read-ahead: 64k on all drives
- NCQ is disabled (state: 1) on all drives

Current mdstat output:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md127 : active raid5 sdf1[6] sdc1[2] sde1[5] sda1[0] sdb1[1] sdd1[4]
      46875004928 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      [==>..................]  reshape = 11.3% (1331219864/11718751232) finish=17768.0min speed=9743K/sec
      bitmap: 0/88 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

So it's quite slow and it's going to take an age to finish. I *can* live with that, but I was wondering if there's anything more I can do to improve performance and the few thoughts I had on this are:

- Stopping the reshape and switching bitmap to external
- Changing the chunk size, if that's even possible

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think I've made this more specific; hope this is OK!